# Display articles according to its specific taxonomy in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal. I google out but could not find the specific answer. May be I am unaware about the terms.

> I want to display articles according to it's specific taxonomy.

Let me describe what I have done. 
I have created two **taxonomy** : **Location and Meeting Type**. And a **Content Type 'Meeting'**. It helps to enter meeting according to the location and meeting type. Location and Meeting type are used as Entity Reference Term (**Reference Taxonomy**).

I have problem while displaying at front end. I wanted to display the list of meeting according to the **Location** and **Meeting Type**.

I have enclosed image which will explain more clearly.

Also please let me know, the way I have done this is proper or not.

Appreciated for your help. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal Views module is your best bet at solving this issue.  You would be able to sort or filter content by taxonomy terms etc.....

Comment: That is right. Even in D8 it's default installed. I have already done all the task from backend (admin section) but don't get idea how to display in  frontend as shown in the image above.

Comment: I don't really understand the specifics of your situation, but you should be able to create filters that users can use to filter by the different locations and meeting types.  One way i would solve this is by creating a Teaser View/that lists all of the meetings with an Exposed Search Filter.  The user would be able to filter the meetings and can then click on the teaser(View) which would take them to the main page of that particular meeting.